Finding the volume of a weird figure
I have a rough sketch of a problem involving a cylinder with fixed radii $r( r = 4 )$ in the picture) and that weird cross-section. The angle between the section xy plane is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. I am asked to find the volume of it (yellow lines for distinguishing). The answer is fairly simple - it's ( $\frac{2}{3} r^2 $), but I cannot figure out why it does not have any $\pi$ in it. Actually, I cannot figure it out at all.
That's the original question, for additional info. Let $r$ be a positive constant. Consider the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 < r^2 $ and let $C$ be the part of the cylinder that satisfies $ 0 \leq z \leq y $. Calculate the volume of $C $, and express it in terms of $r$.
Please, help. Thanks in advance.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

First of all, notice that the plane intersecting the cylinder at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ means that the. plane can be expressed as $$z=x$$
You want to find the volume of the solid region using a double integral of the form
$$Vol=\underset{D}{\int\int}f(x,y)dA$$
the region D  in the xy-plane is bounded by the $x-$axis and the curve $x^2+y^2=r^2$
therefore we get
$$
\begin{align}
Vol&=\underset{D}{\int\int}f(x,y)dA\\
&=\int_{y=-r}^r\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} x dxdy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{y=-r}^r \left(r^2-y^2\right) dy\\
&=\frac{2r^3}{3}
\end{align}
$$

I cannot wrap my head about polar coordinates since day 0, so this explainantion helped a huge lot, thanks! sorry for a typo in the power of r, it's indeed 3.

@takibokyu polarophobia is understandable :) but you will have to overcome it if you want to continue in many branches of Mathematics especialy Applied Mathematics. Besides, have you appreciated the counter-example of the lunes of Hippocrates ?

First of all, it is impossible that the formula for a volume is in $\frac23 r^2$ for a reason of homogeneity. It must be $\frac23 r^3$.
Proof : Up to a rotation that does not change the volume one can take equation $z=\tan (\pi/4)x=x$ for the equation of the cutting plane. Therefore, the volume is to be taken over the domain $D$ defined as the half disk defined by $0 < \rho < r$ and  $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ (we have chosen polar coordinates) :
$$V=\iint_{D}x dx dy=\int_{\rho=0}^{\rho=r} \int_{\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}} \underbrace{\rho \cos \theta}_{x} \underbrace{(\rho d \rho d \theta)}_{dx dy}$$
$$V=\left[\frac13 \rho^3\right]_0^{r} \times \left[\sin \theta\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac23 r^3$$
without $\pi$ in the formula.
In order to answer your question :
It is not because a region is bounded by arcs of circles that the expression of its surface/volume must contain $\pi$, one of the most striking examples being the lunes of Hippocrates.

Arigato for the answer. The OP was expecting a $\pi$ in the expression, since we're dealing with an object that has circles in it.

@Hudjefa Thanks for reminding me to have an argument "against" the necessary presence of $\pi$ : I have given now the counter-example of lunes of Hippocrates.

@Hudjefa I just saw that you have been commenting some time ago a similar question :)

Hidden $\pi$?  $\frac{2}{3} = \pi \times 0.212...$

@Hudjefa Joke appreciated.

The area of a circle of radius $1$ is $\pi,$ which we can approximate by adding the areas of rectangles between chords of the circle.
For half a circle, we can just use the area of half of each rectangle; this has length $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$
Now consider a wedge of a cylinder.
Instead of areas of rectangles, we can use volumes of triangular prisms to approximate the volume of the wedge, where the triangular prisms are approximately the pieces of the wedge between parallel planes.
The base of the triangle in the triangular prism has length $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2},$
just like the half-rectangle when we looked at the circle.
But that triangle also has height $y.$
So the area of the triangle is $\frac12 y^2 = \frac12 - \frac12 x^2,$
and the volume of the prism is just that times the distance between the parallel planes.
Integrating $\frac12 - \frac12 x^2$ is a very different thing from integrating
$\sqrt{1 - x^2}.$ You could say the factor $\pi$ was a result of the square root, which now has disappeared. (That also seems a bit naïve, but at least it recognizes how radically the wedge shape affects the result.)
A geometric explanation is that if you integrate along the diameter of the semicircle, for the flat semicircle you are integrating a function that has a semicircular shape, but for the wedge you end up integrating a function that has a parabolic shape.

The presence of a circular arc is no guarantee that there will be a factor of $\pi$ in the formula for either area or volume, as demonstrated in another answer.
Attempting to make a simple correlation between the presence of circular arcs and factors of $\pi$ in an area or volume formula seems like it would be an incredibly frustrating task.
For example, if we take a line segment of length $2r$ and rotate it in a plane around its midpoint, it generates a disk of diameter $2r,$
which has an area $\pi r^2.$ But when we rotate the disk around one of its diameters to form a solid sphere or "ball" -- adding another dimension of "circularity" to the object, so to speak -- we don't get another factor of
$\pi.$ The volume is just $\frac43 \pi r^3.$
On the other hand, if we rotate the disk around a line in the same plane at a distance $R$ from the center of the disk, where $R > r,$ we get a solid torus of volume $2\pi^2 Rr^2.$
Note that this formula has $\pi^2,$ not just $\pi.$
So we somehow get an extra factor of $\pi$ out of this rotation about an axis that we did not get when the axis passed through the disk's center.
On the other hand again, if we take a three-dimensional ball of radius $r$ and "rotate" it again in four-dimensional space to form a four-dimensional ball of radius $r,$ the four-dimensional volume is $\frac12 \pi^2 r^4.$ So we did get an extra factor of $\pi$ this time, though we still have only two factors for three rotations.
Another example: start with a solid cube of edge length $2r,$ aligned with a set of $x,y,z$ coordinate axes and centered at the origin of the coordinate system.
The volume is $8r^3.$ Intersect the cube with an infinite solid cylinder of radius $r$ whose axis is the $x$-axis. The resulting solid is a finite cylinder of radius $r$ and height $2r,$ with volume $2\pi r^3.$
This kind of makes sense, because we started with an object whose projections onto the coordinate planes were all square, and now we have two projections that are still square but one that is circular.
Now intersect this cylinder with an infinite solid cylinder of radius $r$ whose axis is the $y$-axis. We end up with an object that has circular projections on two of the coordinate planes, not just one. (The remaining projection is still a square.) But instead of two factors of $\pi$ in the volume of this new object, the factor we already had disappears: the volume is
$\frac{16}3 r^3.$
(In fact this last object is just the union of four symmetric cylindrical wedges, and its volume's lack of a factor of $\pi$ is for exactly the same reason as the lack of that factor in the cylindrical wedge's volume.)
So the absence of $\pi$ in the formula of the volume of a cylindrical wedge really shouldn't be very surprising. Factors of $\pi$ come and in the measurements of objects with circular cross sections for reasons that do not always correlate to the presence of circles. You just have to do the calculations carefully to make sure you have all the right factors and none that you shouldn't.

[+1] Interesting arguments. On my side, I had suddenly the remembrance of the counterexample given by the lunes of Hippocrates...
